Is $\frac{||f||_{L^p}^p}{||f||_{L^1}^2} \leq K ||f||_{L^r}^{s}$ possible?
Let $\Omega=(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$ (or, $\Omega$ is any open set in $\mathbb{R}^d$).
Let's consider the usual $L^p(\Omega)$  space with the Lebesgue measure. I'm only assuming $f \geq0$ and $f \in L^p(\Omega)$, where $p>3$.
My question is:
Can we obtain an estimate like
$\frac{||f||_{L^p}^p}{||f||_{L^1}^2} \leq K ||f||_{L^r}^{s}$?
Here,  $K$ is constant and $r \leq p$.
For example, if $f \equiv c$, then $r,s$ can be $p-2$.
If there exists a counterexample, please let me know. Thank you.

No, taking a sequence of functions converging to a function not in $L^p$ but in $L^r$ will show you that there is no constant $K$ independent of $f$. If $1\leq p\leq r$, then yes by Hölder's inequality

@LL3.14
I understand. Thanks a lot!
